# php - use preg_replace for a specific domain name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use the the following pattern in `preg_replace()` to replace a specific domain name from the beginning of all paths in html file. Everything is fine, but the problem is that it replaces the domain names in email addresses also.

```
preg_replace('%(https?://)?(www\.)?domain\.com/?%im', '', '$html')
```

Result shold be like:

```
domain.com/path/ => /path/
www.domain.com/path/ => /path/
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `beginning of file path in html file`; or provide a functional example string? Also the `m` modifier isn't doing anything in your expression.

Comment: Something like: `%(https?://)?(?<!@)(www\.)?domain\.com/?%im` negating the `@`?

Comment: you made the protocol portion optional, so there's no way for the regex to tell between `example.com`-the-email-address and `example.com`-the-web-url

Comment: @AbraCadaver that works somehow.

Comment: @MarcB maybe by mistake of course. I don't want to make the protocol optional. Your solution?

Comment: Aha fixed it: `(https?://)(www\.)?domain\.com/?%im`

Comment: Simple, if it's an email it has an `@` so don't replace those.  If the protocol isn't optional then it must be present for the replacement to happen.

Comment: You don't need the `+` although `https://https://www.domain.com` would be strange. The `?` made it optional; just removing that requires it be present once.

Comment: So `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` won't be replaced, only if they have `http://`

Comment: What about this one? `(http?://)(www\.)?domain\.com/?`

Comment: You can run regexs on regex101.com to see how they perform. That expression makes the `p` on `http` optional, you should put the `s` back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace:

- domain.com
- www.domain.com
- http://domain.com
- http://www.domain.com

But not email address with that domain then you need to use a negative lookbehind for the `@` that is required in an email address:

```
'%(https?://)?(?<!@)(www\.)?domain\.com/?%im'
```

You don't need the `m` modifier and if you don't want to replace the trailing `/` then remove it:

```
'%(https?://)?(?<!@)(www\.)?domain\.com%i'
```